# understand what ∪n∈NUn = (0, 2) ⊃ (0, 1] means

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, discrete-mathematics

Hi I'm trying to understand what the highlighted part in the below image means and how would you say it in words. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which specific part are you confused about? Are you confused about $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$, the equals sign, the $\supset$ sign, $(0, 2)$, or $(0, 1]$?

Comment: It's unfortunate the text's author used $\cup$ (`\cup`) rather than $\bigcup$ (`\bigcup`).

Comment: In words: "The union of the sets $U_n$ for natural numbers $n$ is equal to the set $(0,2)$, which contains $(0,1]$." That's what the notation $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ means. It's the same as $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3 \cup \cdots$ where the union continues for all natural numbers.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information which better conveyed in text.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/.  For an overview of how mathematical typesetting works on this site, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the set of values present in at least one of the sets $U_n$ (for $n$ a positive integer) is the set of values strictly between $0$ and $2$, and this in turn includes all positive values $\le1$.